# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync crash windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, google-api-dotnet-client

I have implemented google login in Windows phone 8.1 store app. It works good normally, I am able to authenticate and get user info.

But, when I have *BackgroundMediaPlayer* running and I call `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown();`. Also if any Task is running canceled those Tasks.

After this if I try to call `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` app crashes after 2 to 3 seconds.

Anyone experienced this, suggestion are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen it before and I don't have much experience with windows phone.  It looks suspicious.   Put it up on the issue forum one of the lead developers might have an idea.   https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues

Comment: This issue is having no reply!

Comment: Looks like, downgrading SDK to 1.9.1 solved problem!